# Macbook Pro Late 2011 15" Inc

Tags: macbook-pro, macos

I currently have a Macbook Pro late 2011 15 inch which is running Mac OS X 10.7.5 which is a little outdated for my preference. When I run a software update there it says there is no software update available and when I open my Appstore it crashes so I can not download the update for El Capitan. Does this version of the Macbook not support later versions of OS X? How can I get around this issue and download El Capitan?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the requirements for upgrading to El Capitan.  Do you meet all the requirements, **especially the free space**?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

http://www.apple.com/osx/how-to-upgrade/#hardware-requirements

El Capitan is usable for MacBoolPro Mid 2007 and newer, so yes your mac can run El Capitan